# Create a custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

With android studio I'm trying to create a custom `ListView`. The app doesn't crash but there aren't the `items` that I'm trying to show on my `ListView`. When I run it here is a `list` but nothing in there in the rows; also I can scroll it and I can click on the rows with no problem.
Here's my `ListView` in `MainActivity`:

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this,myRssFeed.getList());
                adapter.addAll();
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

my `CustomAdapter`:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<RSSItem> web;

public CustomList(Activity context, List<RSSItem> web) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    txtTitle.setText((CharSequence) getTitle());

    return rowView;
}

private RSSItem getTitle() {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating as below

```
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
txtTitle.setText(web.get(pos).getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
private RSSItem getTitle() {
    return null;
}
```

To:

```
private RSSItem getTitle(int position) {
    return web.get(position);
}
```

And change this:

```
txtTitle.setText((CharSequence) getTitle());
```

To:

```
txtTitle.setText((CharSequence) getTitle(position));
```